# JPQL Query not updating database

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, named-query

I have a JPQL with `@NamedQuery` that does not return errors, but also doesn´t update Database.

Here is the Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restricao_decomp")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = RestricaoDecomp.UPDATE_BY_ID, query = "UPDATE RestricaoDecomp a SET a.nome = ?1, "
        + "a.comentar = ?2, a.revisada = ?3 where id = ?4"),
})
public class RestricaoDecomp {

public static final String UPDATE_BY_ID = "RestricaoDecomp.updateById";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int id;

@Column(name = "nome")
String nome;

@Column(name = "comentar")
String comentar;

@Column(name = "data")
LocalDate data;

@Column(name = "revisada")
Integer revisada;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getComentar() {
    return comentar;
}

public void setComentar(String comentar) {
    this.comentar = comentar;
}

public LocalDate getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(LocalDate data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Integer getRevisada() {
    return revisada;
}

public void setRevisada(Integer revisada) {
    this.revisada = revisada;
}
}
```

This is the DAO:

```
@Stateless
public class RestricaoDecompDAO extends AbstractDAO<RestricaoDecomp, Integer> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5926717750595575580L;

public void updateById(String nome, String comentar, Integer revisada, Integer id) {
    executeNamedQuery(RestricaoDecomp.UPDATE_BY_ID, nome, comentar, revisada, id);
}
}
```

And this is how it is called in the `Service`... (The parameters are altered in the object. The debug shows it.)

```
restricaoDecompDAO.updateById(restricao.getNome(), restricao.getComentar(), 1, restricao.getId());
```

But... When the method `updateById` is called, nothing happens... And I get no errors... It just doesn´t update, and doesn´t return any errors... What the hell is happening?

PS: I'm not using Spring, just JPA... It is driving me crazy! No errors, no update... PLEASE HELP! =) Thanks!

PS: I have other `@NamedQueries` (not with UPDATE, but SELECT), that works just fine....

Comment: Post the detail of executeNamedQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. This is what I did:

```
public void update(RestricaoDecomp rd, RestricaoDecompDAO dao) {
    if (rd == null)
        return;
    
    RestricaoDecomp rdDB = dao.findById(rd.getId());
    
    if (rdDB == null)
        return;
    
    rdDB.setComentar(rd.getComentar());
    rdDB.setRevisada(1);
    rdDB.setNome(rd.getNome());
    
    dao.update(rdDB);
}
```

The Object in first method param contains the changes I wanted to persist, and the dao is an object which is `@Inject` in the Service.

The `AbstractDAO` extending class has an update method, that finally worked (But if I called the update from Abstract right from the service, it didn´t worked either.

The AbstractDAO implemented the `@PersistenceContext` and `EntityManager`

I believe that somehow it was a problem with the UPDATE statement of the Query, since the SELECTs were working just fine.

Well, that's it! =)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this :

```
@Stateless
public class RestricaoDecompDAO extends AbstractDAO<RestricaoDecomp, Integer> {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void updateById(String nome, String comentar, Integer revisada, Integer id) {
        if(id == null) return;          
        var o = em.find(RestricaoDecomp.class, id);
        if(o == null) return;
        o.setNome(nome);
        o.setComentar(comentar);
        o.setRevisada(revisada);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Though it didn´t work in my case. I managed to get it working, the solution is below.